# amcharts 4 category X axis labels not aligned with graphed data

Tags: amcharts, axis-labels

Using rotated labels on category X axis. (Real graph uses long names but results are the same.)
A: Alignment of axis labels and their data points is fine without label rotation.
B: Labels are not aligned when rotated.
The only difference between A and B graph coding is the addition of `"labels":{"rotation":90}` in the xAxes renderer.
How can alignment be fixed?

[image: A: unrotated labels; B: rotated labels]

```
var chart =am4core.createFromConfig({
  "colors":         { "list": ["#DB3", "#000", "#888"] },
  "data":           [$data],
  "legend":         {   "markers":{"width":20, "height":10},
                        "position":"top",
                        "useDefaultMarker":true
    },
  "series": [
        {   "dataFields":       { "categoryX":"X", "valueY":"Y1" },
            "name":             "[font-size:16px;font-weight:600;]{$n1}[/]",
            "strokeWidth":      2,
            "type":             "LineSeries"
      },
        {   "dataFields":       { "categoryX":"X", "valueY":"Y2" },
            "name":             "[font-size:16px;font-weight:600;]{$n2}[/]",
            "strokeWidth":      2,
            "type":             "LineSeries"
      },
        {   "dataFields":       { "categoryX":"X", "valueY":"Y3" },
            "name":             "[font-size:16px;font-weight:600;]others[/]",
            "strokeWidth":      2,
            "type":             "LineSeries"
      }
    ],
    "xAxes": [
        {   "dataFields":       {   "category": "X" },
            "renderer":         {   "minGridDistance":11, "labels":{"rotation":90}},
            "type":                 "CategoryAxis"
        }
    ],
    "yAxes": [
        {   "renderer":         {"minGridDistance":15},
            "title":                {"text": "[font-size:16px;font-weight:600;]Values[/]"},
            "type":                 "ValueAxis"
    }]
}, "line", am4charts.XYChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

LABELS renderer needed `"verticalCenter":"middle"` with rotation.
I don't know how many other things I tried!